# Javascript of Joomla with $E is Not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, mootools

hmmmm....

I'm abit confused.

i have a module taken from the earlier of joomla 1.5
that I tried to implement it inside joomla 1.6.

When I tried to refresh my page,
it will always generate this error;

> $E is not defined
>   Source File: http://localhost/p.net/templates/jabellatrix/scripts/ja.collapsible.js
>   Line: 13

What is that?? I dunno.
Whether it is a mooTools problem or jquery problem i dunno.

Is there anyone could share a bit of words about this?

anyway here comes the javascript source code that's mentioned above; [Source Code Link](http://db.tt/9KPiVuY).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means, you have old code. $E is from mootools 1.1x and it refers to `document.getElement("selector");` to return the first matching element. you can either go:

`$E = document.getElement;` in the hope it makes it compatible or look at another collapsible script that is more up-to date. chances are - this wont be the only breaking api change.

the full code was:

```
/* 
Function: $E
    Selects a single (i.e. the first found) Element based on the selector passed in and an optional filter element.
    Returns as <Element>.

Arguments:
    selector - string; the css selector to match
    filter - optional; a DOM element to limit the scope of the selector match; defaults to document.

Example:
    >$E('a', 'myElement') //find the first anchor tag inside the DOM element with id 'myElement'

Returns:
    a DOM element - the first element that matches the selector
*/

function $E(selector, filter){
    return ($(filter) || document).getElement(selector);
};
```

Comment: waaah,
i encountered a new problem here...
I actually follow ur tips to grab the ($(filter) || document).getElement(selector); 

but, whamm!
I got another null value over the line 

el.elmain.getStyle('height').toInt();

is it invalid to use it over the source code I share over (above)?